# How efficient WebMatrix is?

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, razor

I couldn't find any information on this. I know it's used for basic pages but compared to MVC or WebForms how efficient WebMatrix is? Or is there any good advantage of using it over MVC/WebForms for basic pages besides Razor syntax?

Comment: Do you mean efficient in coding, or efficient at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebMatrix is an editor.

It has no effect on the efficiency of the pages it creates.

**EDIT**: Razor pages are pre-compiled, just like ASPX pages.
They should not be noticeably slower.

In addition, they are likely to be more efficient than WebForms server-side controls, since there's no ViewState.

Comment: sorry, what I meant is when you create a CSHTML or VBHTML page using Razor syntax how well and how fast it is handled by IIS compared to aspx pages. I hope the question makes sense =)

Comment: Can WebMatrix be used to create and maintain MVC3 web-sites?

Comment: @Shimmy: I don't know.  It probably wouldn't do it very well.  Use VS.

Comment: The question if they can work together, I wanna start a new website, but it seems there is only a web-app project for MVC3, am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

WebMatrix is not a replacement for MVC or WebForms, it's a development environment that contains light weight versions of IIS and SQL Server.

You can develop web applications in it, but you still need a Windows server if you want to deploy the application.